# Python dataframe: splitting 4 columns into multiple columns based on years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I am trying to split a dataframe of 4 columns, similar as the one above:

```
id_inf  id_prov  year      total
     9      676  2007     600.00
     9      676  2008     150.00
     9    34957  2007      18.75
     9    34957  2008      12.50
     9   185304  2007     296.94
     9   189095  2009   12048.90
    54       54  2015       6.54
    54    12088  2009      63.00
    ..      ...   ...        ...
```

into a dataframe that the values of each year is separated in different columns. I need a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id_inf  id_prov   t_2007  t_2008   t_2009  ... t_2015  
     9      676   600.00  150.00      NaN  ...    NaN      
     9    34957    18.75   12.50      NaN  ...    NaN
     9   185304   296.94     NaN  2048.90  ...    NaN 
    54       54      NaN     NaN      NaN  ...   6.54
    54    12088      NaN     NaN    63.00  ...    NaN
    ..      ...      ...     ...      ...  ...    ...
```

I've been trying to use pivot tables, to get something similar but it isn't working as I need. Can somebody can give me any guidance on how can I achieve this?.

Thanks

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['id_inf', 'id_prov'], columns='year', values='total').add_prefix('t_').reset_index()`

Comment: @coldspeed TKS!!